# Group id not showing up in HTML when using routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, ngroute

I am having some difficulty getting routeParams to work for my site. I am attempting to have a list of groups displayed with the ability to select one and be routed to a page with that groups specific details. I asked a similar question yesterday but don't think I knew exactly what to ask for. The way I have it set up now I only see
      '/#/viewgroup/:id' 
in the browser instead of the actual id number and the page is blank. Thank you for the help!

ROUTES:

```
 .whenAuthenticated('/viewgroup/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/groups/groupDetail.html',
    controller: 'GroupCtrl'
  })
```

INDEX.HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="group in data.groups | filter: filterObject | filter: search">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h5 class="panel-title"><a href="#viewgroup/:id">{{group.name}}</a></h5>
  </div>
```

GROUPDETAIL.HTML:

```
<div ng-show="group in data.groups">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
    <li class="active">{{group.name}}</li>
 </ol>
```

GROUPCTRL:
I am only using the 'groups/data.json' for the data because I am not sure how to pull in this data from the firebase server. Pulling from the server is really what I need.

```
creativeBillingApp.controller('GroupCtrl', ['$scope', 'groupsService', '$routeParams',  function( $scope, groupsService, $firebase, $routeParams, $http) {

$http.get('groups/data.json').success(function(data){
    angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
      if (item.id == $routeParams.groupId) 
        $scope.group = item;
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a lot of moving parts in this question, which leads to my answer fixing one problem but not another. Can you set up a plunkr/fiddle/bin that reproduces a single problem at a time?

Comment: thanks Frank! I set up a Plunker. It's not exactly working but i believe it has all of the code I need. http://plnkr.co/edit/PKRcoO7J1B947a6I0UF3?p=preview

Comment: You haven't mentioned here that you are using angularFire-seed (i.e. what whenAuthenticated() is, since that's not a $routeParams method), nor does your plunkr show this code or recreate the problem. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

The `:id` syntax is only used in the routeProvider to indicate where it should look for the `id` value in the URL. In the view you use the normal `{{}}` or `ng-bind` notation to inject that `id` value into the generated HTML.

Assuming that your `groups` is the result of a `$firebase(ref).$asArray()` somewhere, you can access the id value of each item using `$id`.

So where you now have `<a href="#viewgroup/:id">` in your index.html, simply put `<a href="#viewgroup/{{group.$id}}">`. Angular will substitute that for the group id when it renders the template.

Comment: Thank you Frank! So, I am now successfully getting the id into my browser but the template is not appearing and I am not recieving any errors in the console.

Comment: I fixed the groupdetail.html by adding ng-show="group in data.groups" now the template is appearing but the data is not pulling into the page. I am recieving this error; Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'in' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [group in data.groups] starting at [in data.groups]..

Comment: The correct use of `in` is with `ng-repeat`. Using it in `ng-show="group in data.groups"` is invalid angular syntax.